# Send message to Kafka when SessionWindows was started and ended

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to send a message to the Kafka topic when new SessionWindow was created and when was ended. I have the following code

```
stream
    .filter(user -> user.isAdmin)
    .keyBy(user -> user.username)
    .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(10)))
//what now? Trigger?
```

Now I want to send message when new session was started (with some metadata like web browser and timestamps, these informations are available in each element of stream) and send message to Kafka when session was ended (in this example 10 seconds after last element I think) with number of total requests.

It's possible in Flink? I think I should use some trigger but I don't know how and I can't find any example.

Comment: Do You want to have it in real-time ? I.e. Do You want to write to Kafka when the session starts (at the exact moment of start) or You want to do this when the window is processed ?? (after the session ends)

Comment: real time, when the window is processed. I want to analyse logs and show red light when admin is doing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom window trigger.

1. How to tell a new session is started?
   You can create a `ValueState` with the default value to null, so in case the state value is null, it is a session start.
2. When the session ended?
   Just before `TriggerResult.FIRE`.

Here is a demo based on `ProcessingTimeTrigger` of Flink, I only put the question-related logics here, you can check other details from the source code.

```
public class MyProcessingTimeTrigger extends Trigger<Object, TimeWindow> {
    // a state which keeps a session start.
    private final ValueStateDescriptor<Long> stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<Long>("session-start", Long.class);

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ValueState<Long> state = ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDescriptor);
        if(state.value() == null) {
            // if value is null, it's a session start.
            state.update(window.getStart());
        }

        ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(window.maxTimestamp());
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) {
        // here is a session end.
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDescriptor).clear();
        ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(window.maxTimestamp());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to do this when the window is processed, then You can simply use the `WindowProcessFunction`, basically what You need to do is to add `.process(new MyProcessFunction()` to Your code. In the `ProcessFunction` You can have access to the whole window including its first (start) and last (end) element. You can simply use the Side output to just output the beginning and the end of the given window. You can then create a stream from side output and sink it to Kafka. More on Side outputs can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html).

Comment: I've tried to extend the `ProcessWindowFunction` class. But I have no idea how to distinguish first element and which method is called when the window is closed. Every time the `process` method is called it's the last element I think

Comment: `process` is called  with the Sequence of elements not with one element :) So You can easily get the first and the last element from the sequence.

Comment: I still don't understand :( If `process` is called with all elements there is no way to send a message at the beginning because session is ended (you have all elements). If `process` is called with partital data there is no 'last element' indicator

Comment: Yeah from Your comment I have understood that You are ok with sending the alerts when the window is processed and the window is processed after it is closed :)